# Is there any way to call useEffect hook after resetting all the states

Tags: reactjs

In my App.tsx file I want to rest all the states and call the useEffect hook to get the quiz data. When it runs first time it runs perfectly but when I click handleRetake function to retake quiz it reset all the states but didn't call useEffect hook to call API.
Here is my code

```
function App() {

  let [quiz,setQuiz] = useState<QuizType[]>([])
  let [currentStep,setCurrentStep] = useState(0)
  let [score,setScore] = useState(0)
  let [showResult, setShowResult] = useState(false)


  

  useEffect(()=>{
    async function fetchData() {
      

      const questions = await getQuizDetails(5,'easy')

      setQuiz(questions)
      
    }
    fetchData();
  },[])

  const handleRetake = (event:React.FormEvent<EventTarget>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setCurrentStep(0)
    setQuiz([])
    setShowResult(false)
    setScore(0)
}
  
  

  if(!quiz.length)
    return <Container>
        <h1>Loading ..... </h1>
    </Container>
  
  if(showResult){
    return(
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col md={{span:6 , offset:3}}>
            <Card>
              <Card.Header>
                Result
              </Card.Header>
              <Card.Body>
                <h1>Your Score is {score} out of {quiz.length}</h1>
                <Button onClick={handleRetake}> Retake Quiz</Button>
              </Card.Body>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is to add `quiz` to dependency list of `useEffect` and add a check such that whenever the `quiz` is an empty list, refetch it.

```
  useEffect(()=>{
   if(quiz.length === 0) {
    async function fetchData() {
      const questions = await getQuizDetails(5,'easy')
      setQuiz(questions)
    }
   fetchData();
   }
  },[quiz])
```

Also this is just one of the way to meet your requirements. You can actually declare `fetchData` outside `useEffect` as well to reuse it whenever you require it. Also with this method, you will have to ensure that your `getQuizDetails` returns a non-empty list otherwise you'll be stuck in a loop of fetching list again and again.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that was hinted upon by @lakshya-thakur in his answer at the end but I feel is of immense importance.

From what I have learnt/experienced so far, we should avoid letting API/function calls which change the value of a state variable be triggered on the state update itself. Instead, removing dependency of the API/function call on state updates and instead triggering them on an external/user-based event (initial page render - `useEffect(()=>{},[])`and/or button clicks) would prevent unnecessary component re-renders and provide a better and more robust solution. This also removes unnecessary checks inside `useEffect` that would be required to decide whether the state needs an update or API/function call needs to be made too.

In the code below, the `initQuizData` function is called on the initial component render and also on clicking the `retake quiz` button. As you can see the API/function call `getQuizDetails` is no more dependent on the state variable `quiz`'s value and instead dependent on external factors that actually intend to make that API/function call.

As opposed the `fetchData` being called every time the `quiz` state is updated (which I agree was just once before the quiz and once after the quiz in this case but following the same pattern one might end up doing this for states that change frequently), here `initQuizData` is called only exactly when it is required and hence no condition checks are necessary inside it.

```js
function App() {

  let [quiz,setQuiz] = useState<QuizType[]>([]);
  let [currentStep,setCurrentStep] = useState(0);
  let [score,setScore] = useState(0);
  let [showResult, setShowResult] = useState(false);

  useEffect(()=>{
    initQuizData();
  },[]);

  const initQuizData = async () => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setCurrentStep(0);
    setQuiz([]);
    setShowResult(false);
    setScore(0);
    const questions = await getQuizDetails(5,'easy');
    setQuiz(questions);
  };
  
  if(!quiz.length)
    return <Container>
        <h1>Loading ..... </h1>
    </Container>
  
  if(showResult){
    return(
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col md={{span:6 , offset:3}}>
            <Card>
              <Card.Header>
                Result
              </Card.Header>
              <Card.Body>
                <h1>Your Score is {score} out of {quiz.length}</h1>
                <Button onClick={initQuizData}> Retake Quiz</Button>
              </Card.Body>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    );
  }
```

The above solution is rough and I have not tested it personally. I just wanted to convey the idea that I stated above as an approach to handle such cases.